# JavaScript's console.log printing unwanted characters

Tags: javascript, console.log

So basically what I'm trying to do is print a simple string to the screen using the console.log function. 
Here's an example :

```
const fromLabel: string = '["' + "AppExp" + '"]' + '\n' + '["' + "AppExp" + '"]';
```

And I ultimately wanna print it, so I go:

```
console.log(fromLabel);
```

and my output is:

```
[\"AppExp\"]\n[\"AppExp\"]
```

So, basically no carriage return and unwanted '\'.

Any idea what could be the problem?

**EDIT: Never mind. I was working with objects and to print them I used JSON.stringify.. little did I know I used it on this string as well ..my bad**

Comment: That's just the console trying to be helpful.

Comment: @Pointy could it not?

Comment: The Console is not meant to render the output the way you'd see it on a page. For that, test it in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Backslashes are escaping certain characters in the string. Your string is put together in a weird way—you're mixing `""` and `''`. Try this:

```js
var str = '["' + 'AppExp' + '"]' + '\n' + '["' + 'AppExp' + '"]'
console.log(str)
```

Comment: Never mind. I was working with objects and to print them I used JSON.stringify.. little did I know I used it on this string as well ..my bad.

Comment: Noice @sadElephent glad you got it sorted. JSON.stringify always works best for me too.

Answer (score 0):

try this code with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

I omitted the `: string` to be able to run the snippet but remember to add it!

```js
const fromLabel = `[""AppExp""]
[""AppExp""]`;
console.log(fromLabel);
```

or in case you do not want duplicate `"` chars

```
const fromLabel: string = `["AppExp"]
["AppExp"]`;
```

I hope it helps! :)

Comment: Never mind. I was working with objects and to print them I used JSON.stringify.. little did I know I used it on this string as well ..my bad